# Android tablelayout row padding

Tags: android, android-tablelayout

I want to create a table with buttons on the right of the rows as shown below.  I want to set padding for the right of each row but this "eats into" the right most button.  Is there a way of having the padding without compromising the display of the buttons?

[image: Screen shot of the table layout]

Here's my layout xml code:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:padding="10dp" >

<TableLayout 
    android:id="@+id/tbl_test"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#000000"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_marginTop="1dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="1dp"
    android:stretchColumns="1"
    >

     <TableRow android:background="#ffffff" android:layout_margin="1dp">

        <TextView android:text="Col 1" android:layout_column="0" />
        <TextView android:text="Col 2" android:layout_column="1" />
        <TextView android:text="Col 3" android:layout_column="2" />
        <TextView android:text="Col 4" android:layout_column="3" />

    </TableRow>

     <TableRow
         android:background="#ffffff"
         android:layout_marginLeft="1dp"
         android:layout_marginRight="1dp"
         android:layout_marginBottom="1dp">

         <TextView android:text="r1" android:layout_column="0" />
         <TextView android:text="padding right 0dp" android:layout_column="1" />
         <Button android:text="edit" />
        <Button android:text="delete" />

    </TableRow>

     <TableRow
         android:background="#ffffff"
         android:layout_marginLeft="1dp"
         android:layout_marginRight="1dp"
         android:layout_marginBottom="1dp"
         android:paddingRight="2dp">

        <TextView android:text="r2" android:layout_column="0" />
        <TextView android:text="padding right 1dp" android:layout_column="1" />
        <Button android:text="edit" />
        <Button android:text="delete" />

    </TableRow>

     <TableRow
         android:background="#ffffff"
         android:layout_marginLeft="1dp"
         android:layout_marginRight="1dp"
         android:layout_marginBottom="1dp"
         android:paddingRight="3dp">

        <TextView android:text="r3" android:layout_column="0" />
        <TextView android:text="padding right 2dp" android:layout_column="1" />
        <Button android:text="edit" />
        <Button android:text="delete" />

    </TableRow>

     <TableRow
         android:background="#ffffff"
         android:layout_marginLeft="1dp"
         android:layout_marginRight="1dp"
         android:layout_marginBottom="1dp"
         android:paddingRight="4dp">

        <TextView android:text="r4" android:layout_column="0" />
        <TextView android:text="padding right 3dp" android:layout_column="1" />
        <Button android:text="edit" />
        <Button android:text="delete" />

    </TableRow>

</TableLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know why the problem with the clipping happens but one easy way to fix it and obtain the same appearance is to remove the `paddingRight` attribute from the `TableRows` and also add the attribute `layout_marginRight`(set to the padding value) on the last item of the row, the delete `Button`.

Answer (score 2):

try

```
android:stretchColumns="0,1,2"
```

this would solve the problem after